# Internet Recovery

Tags: macos

I went to update a few older (2011) iMacs the other day using the Command + Option + R combo in an attempt to have them update to 10.13.3.  It was my understanding that this would work but they defaulted to what had been installed.  Today I read that this option became available beginning with 10.12.4.

Does that mean the machine has to be 10.12.4 installed before it will upgrade to 10.12.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that each Mac must have had macOS 10.12.4 installed first in order for <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to install the newest version of macOS available for the device.

Check out [How to Reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904);

> If you haven't already updated to macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later, Option-Command-R installs the macOS that came with your Mac, or the version closest to it that is still available.